# Auto download in-app purchase (iap) report for amazon android app

Tags: android, amazon-in-app-purchase

We have an app running on amazon store, which have in-app purchases. Through amazon's developer portal we can view/download the sales/earnings report. Our goal is to accumulate the data from different appstores- google, iOS appstore, amazon at one place, so that we can analyse the data better. We were able to do this for google playstore and ios appstore.

Is there a way to download the report programmatically from amazon store, or any other solution for the goal mentioned?